# Is this faux docroot too flaky?

Tags: .htaccess

I like storing my application's PHP files above the docroot.

However, my shared host stores a lot of crap there as well. It looks cluttered.

I was wondering about doing this...

```
users/alex/public_html/
 - .htaccess
 - application/
 - system/

users/alex/public_html/www/
 - index.php
 - assets/css
 - assets/js
```

Where the `.htaccess` file contains this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* www/$0
```

So, all requests to my web root are silently rewritten to the `www/` folder.

Is this too flaky?

Comment: What do you mean by "flaky"? Also, note that without a few additional rules, your public content would also be viewable via `example.com/www/index.php` and so on. Not a huge issue, but it might be desirable to limit a given page to one valid URL.

Comment: @Tim Stone Sorry, I meant, *what risks am I taking?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think that there's any real risk involved. Essentially, you're putting the same trust in the web server to do its job as you do with it limiting web access to the document root. There are a couple of points to consider though.

First, mod_rewrite rule sets in .htaccess files are selectively evaluated in terms of specificity. With a URL of */category/path/* and the following directory structure (assuming all .htaccess files have mod_rewrite rule sets), only the .htaccess file in *path/* will be evaluated.

```
public_html/
|- .htaccess
|- category/
   |- .htaccess
   |- path/
      |- .htaccess
```

So, why is this an issue? If you had an .htaccess file in one of your application folders that was supposed to be above the document root, assuming it had at least `RewriteEngine On` in it, the RewriteRule in your root .htaccess file wouldn't be applied. This is easily avoidable though.

Secondly, *every* request (including those for static resources) will not only incur the overhead of parsing the .htaccess file, but will also take at least one internal redirect. I don't consider this overhead to be very significant, but if your site were high-traffic, it may have a (mildly) noticeable impact. At that point though, you'd be better suited with more flexible hosting anyway, which would make this process unnecessary.

With those issues in mind, I don't think you're any worse off going ahead and doing the rewrite to shift the effective document root. Even if you were to mess up the .htaccess file somehow, mod_rewrite will throw an internal server error in cases where the configuration is invalid, so your only cause for concern would be a rule which did something other than you expected.

With respect to that, I'd recommend making the following changes:

**/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* /www/$0
```

**/www/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if the original request was to /www/something and redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/www/
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]

# The rest of your rules...
```

Comment: @alex Happy to help. I didn't test the rule set, so if you opt to use it, let me know if there are any issues. Looks alright from here, but I've been known to let a typo slip in every now and then.

Comment: @Tim Stone I'm trying to prevent something like `/www/assets/css/common.css` from being accessed. However, the rules aern't matching it I don't think. Also, for the last RewriteRule, I changed that `^` to `.*`.

Comment: @alex Whoops, you're right, that second rule should have had `.*` as the test pattern. Corrected the answer now. With regard to preventing `/www/...`, the first condition/rule pair performs the redirect to auto-correct as expected on my test server, you're saying nothing happens on your end?

Comment: @Tim Stone I think it may have something to do with my `.htaccess` rules within `/www/`. I map all URLs to `index.php` which are not file (`-f`) or a directory (`-d`).

Comment: @alex Ah, so you do have mod_rewrite rules in `/www/`. I should have asked that first, sorry. Moving the top portion of the example to the top of that .htaccess file should hopefully clear things up. You won't need it in the document root .htaccess file, since all requests to `/www/...` will be handled by the `/www/` .htaccess exclusively.

Comment: @Tim Stone Thanks so much for getting back to me!

Comment: @Tim Stone I placed that first condition and rule into `/www/.htaccess` and still no go. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @alex I'm having an off day, it seems, heh. At any rate, I've updated answer. The second rule needed to be modified when it was moved; see if that helps.

Comment: Maybe it is because I am using `RewriteBase` in both `.htaccess`, so `\www` isn't where I'd think it be.

Comment: @alex No problem. If changing the rule as I did above is failing still, what is your RewriteBase in the `/www/` .htaccess? (Though it shouldn't make a difference, I'm trying to think if it's even used in this case or not)

Comment: `RewriteBase /~new/`, because all of this is currently under a `/~new/` folder.

Comment: @alex Ah...Hm. The RewriteBase will in no way interfere with the rules matching, but... In the RewriteCond, did you update "/www/" to "/~new/"? If so, mod_rewrite also tries to expand ~ paths to userdirs, which may be a potential issue...

Comment: @Tim Stone I tried that. Just out of interest, I don't understand this regex `^[A-Z]+\s/www/`. Why do you need to match a space? Is that matching against `GET http://example.com`?

Comment: @alex That's correct. By looking at the raw request sent to the server, you can determine if the current request path is due to your internal redirection, or was entered by the user as such (which is the case you want to redirect in). I'll try the setup with your `/~new/` directory name on my test server and see if there are any problems that crop up. Otherwise, it's working for me, so I'm not sure where the issue is. Unfortunately it's hard to tell in your case too, since if you're on shared hosting you can't turn on mod_rewrite logging.

Comment: @Tim Stone Yes, they are so hard to debug! I wish I could upvote more than once, you've been very helpful. I'll vote up some of your other useful answers :)